# How do i run my Selenium Scripts on Eclipse using batch files?

Tags: java, eclipse, batch-file, selenium

I have multiple Java Selenium scripts, and I want to be able to run them all using one batch file. However, I am not sure how to call/run my Selenium scripts from Eclipse in the batch file.

I've tried multiple approaches that I found, but none of them seem to work for me. If it helps, I have the following folder/files within `%USERPROFILE%\workspace\ChromeProject`:

- `.settings` (folder)
- `bin` (folder)
- `src` (folder)
- `.classpath`
- `.project`

Edit:
Here's what I have tried so far.

First I tried these two methods I found:

Method #1

```
cd C:\Workspace\projectname
java -cp C:\Workspace\projectname\lib\*;C:\Workspace\projectname\bin org.testng.TestNG testng.xml
```

Method #2

```
cd C:\Workspace\projectname
set ProjectPath=C:\Workspace\projectname
echo %ProjectPath%
set classpath=%ProjectPath%\bin;%ProjectPath%\lib\*
echo %classpath%
java org.testng.TestNG %ProjectPath%\testng.xml
```

However, for these methods, I do not actually have a 'lib' folder, so I don't know what to use here. I've tried different folders instead, but can't seem to find the correct approach.
I then tried using the same structure as I did for my Sikulix batch files, as so:

```
@CALL %USERPROFILE%\Desktop\SikuliXdocs\runsikulix.cmd -r %USERPROFILE%\Desktop\ACC_L10nTest\Login02.sikuli
```

However, that various path I use do not seem to work, because I am not actually sure what I should be calling in order to get them to run.

Comment: _"I've tried multiple approaches"_ is nice, but what about showing us your attempts, and what you mean exactly with _"non of them seem to work for me"_?

Comment: Hi aschipfl, that's a fair point. I have edited the original post with updates on my various approaches. Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 0):

I have tried running selenium test using apache ant. You will get and eclipse plugin for apache ant, install it in eclipse. Export build.xml (Ant buildfile) for you project (Eclipse Ant plugin will help you). Now you can directly run your test by :

set JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25

ant.bat -buildfile D:/Myproject/build.xml MyMain

General : "ant bin path "       -buildfile   "build.xml path"   "Target class containing main method"

You can also you TestNG and MAVEN. I recommend **MAVEN with testNG**. not the only testNG. You are using only testNG.